# Matrix Elements of the raising and lowering operators for angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, matrix-elements

I was taught in our chemistry spectroscopy class (NMR module) that the matrix elements of $J_+$ and $J_-$ operators are respectively $\sqrt{(s-m)(s+m+1)}\hbar$ and $\sqrt{(s+m)(s-m+1)}\hbar$, but the prof. remarked that he would not give any proof to this in an elementary spectroscopy class. I searched for the proof in "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths" and a few online resources but couldn't find one.

I would be helped if someone gives the proof to me. Link(s) to appropriate webpage(s) will also work.

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum) help?

Comment: It is there. Thanks @Jakob. I checked only chem-libretexts and couldn't find the proof there.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240668/84967

Comment: the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix is 0.

Answer (score 3):

These are not eigenvalues: they are matrix elements.  Thus for instance
$$
J_+\vert \ell ,m \rangle=\hbar\sqrt{(\ell-m)(\ell+m+1)}\vert \ell, m+1\rangle\, .
$$

In fact since there is always a power $k$ such that $(J_\pm)^k=0$, these operators are nilpotent.  They have $\vert \ell, \pm \ell\rangle$ as their only eigenstate with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: I am sorry. I messed up. These are not eigenvalues since the transformed vector is different. They are matrix elements.

Comment: I corrected the question (since I can't delete), although I got the answer to it.

Comment: @AvinandanMondal actually I chose to answer precisely because of the error, as many less experienced users often confuse eigenvalues with matrix elements.  This “error” is a good learning moment.